# Column-wise dot product in Eigen C++

Tags: c++, linear-algebra, eigen

Is there an easy way to evaluate the column wise dot product of 2 matrices (lets call them `A` and `B`, of type `Eigen::MatrixXd`) that have dimensions `mxn`, without evaluating `A*B` or without having to resort to `for` loops? The resulting vector would need to have dimensions of `1xn` or `nx1`. Also, I'm trying to do this with Eigen in C++

Comment: Element-wise multiply, then sum?  In MATLAB it would be `sum(A .* B)`.  Eigen provides those operations, but I don't know the exact names of the calls.

Comment: nice one! That should work. Thanks!

Comment: Can use an "Eigen::Map" to reshape the matrices into vectors, then take their inner product.

Comment: @Zedd: If my comment provides the hint you needed to make working code, please answer your own question showing future visitors how it is done using Eigen functions.

Answer (score 14):

There are many ways to achieve this, all performing lazy evaluation:

```
res = (A.array() * B.array()).colwise().sum();
res = (A.cwiseProduct(B)).colwise().sum();
```

And my favorite:

```
res = (A.transpose() * B).diagonal();
```

Comment: One curious question: By appending diagonal to the dot product operation, would Eigen only calculate the (ith row of A) dot product (ith col of B) internally so that it would avoid unnecessary calculation? For these three implementation which one would be faster? (Since the 1st and 2nd would avoid unnecessary calculation).

Comment: As written in the answer they `all perform lazy evaluation`, so the last one does compute the diagonal entries only. They are expected to generate roughly the same code. You can check on compiler explorer.

Comment: Will `(A.transpose() * B).diagonal();` have the right asymptotic performance?

Meanwhile, how come `A.colwise().dot(B.colwise())` doesn't work?

Answer (score 3):

I did experiment based on @ggael's answer.

```
MatrixXd A = MatrixXd::Random(600000,30);
MatrixXd B = MatrixXd::Random(600000,30);

MatrixXd res;
clock_t start, end;
start = clock();
res.noalias() = (A * B.transpose()).diagonal();
end = clock();
cout << "Dur 1 : " << (end - start) / (double)CLOCKS_PER_SEC << endl;

MatrixXd res2;
start = clock();
res2 = (A.array() * B.array()).rowwise().sum();
end = clock();
cout << "Dur 2 : " << (end - start) / (double)CLOCKS_PER_SEC << endl;

MatrixXd res3;
start = clock();
res3 = (A.cwiseProduct(B)).rowwise().sum();
end = clock();
cout << "Dur 3 : " << (end - start) / (double)CLOCKS_PER_SEC << endl;
```

And the output is:

```
Dur 1 : 10.442
Dur 2 : 8.415
Dur 3 : 7.576
```

Seems that the diagonal() solution is the slowest one. The cwiseProduct one is the fastest. 
And the memory usage is the same.

Comment: @ggael, please feel free to comment.

Comment: I performed a very similar test but used 16x3 single precision matrices and performed each operation a million times. Using `clang++ -O3` I had times 175, 129, 131 milliseconds which is similar to your results.

Answer (score 1):

Here is how I'd do it with an `Eigen::Map` (assuming real matrices, can extend to complex via taking the adjoint), where `rows` and `cols` denote the number of rows/columns:

```
#include <Eigen/Dense>
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    Eigen::MatrixXd A(2, 2);
    Eigen::MatrixXd B(2, 2);
    A << 1, 2, 3, 4;
    B << 5, 6, 7, 8;

    int rows = 2, cols = 2;

    Eigen::VectorXd vA = Eigen::Map<Eigen::VectorXd>(
                             const_cast<double *>(A.data()), rows * cols, 1);
    Eigen::VectorXd vB = Eigen::Map<Eigen::VectorXd>(
                             const_cast<double *>(B.data()), rows * cols, 1);

    double inner_prod = (vA.transpose() * vB).sum();

    std::cout << inner_prod << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: Now I see that you want a vector as the result? That is, are you after a \vect{result} where each component is A(i,)*B(:,i)' ?

Comment: Yeah, thats right. I'm not sure how this would translate into the code you have above.