# How to multiply matrix with another matrix rowwise in Eigen?

Tags: c++, matrix, eigen, eigen3

I need to multiply two matrices rowwise. I am trying to do recreate matlab's `dot()` operation where `dim` can be mentioned to perform per column/row multiplication.

```
Eigen::MatrixXf mat_1 = Eigen::MatrixXf::Random(10, 3);
Eigen::MatrixXf mat_2 = Eigen::MatrixXf::Random(10, 3);

auto product_mat = mat_1.array().rowwise() * mat_2.array().rowwise().transpose();
```

This is my attempt. I know this is wrong as rowwise operation is returning the type that doesn't have a transpose operation, but I can't figure out how to do this right. I don't want to run a loop and access a row using .row(i) if possible. Also, please mention any resource, other than docs, that could be a quick read regarding how to do eigen's broadcasting and other useful operations. I am having a difficult time writing my own code fast. Thanks.

Comment: What's the size of the matrix you want to end up with?

Comment: Sum each row of the element-wise product of two arrays.

Comment: Oh, also auto doesn't do the computation, you have to assign it to a MatrixXf.

Comment: @Rzu Ok, I will try this out. @Matthieu Brucher I want a `10x1` matrix

Comment: Thanks it works.

Answer (score 1):

This is a duplicate of [Column-wise dot product in Eigen C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27030554).

In short you can also see it as extracting the diagonal of a normal product:

```
VectorXd res = (mat_1 * mat_2.tranpose()).diagonal();
```

Thanks to lazy evaluation, only the diagonal coeffs will be computed, no overhead.